# Make Custom SwiftLint action regex ignore comments

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

I have a custom SwiftLint action to flag up `print()` statements:

```
custom_rules:
    disable_print:
      included: ".*\\.swift"
      name: "print usage"
      regex: "((\\bprint)|(Swift\\.print))\\s*\\("
      message: "Don't use print"
      severity: error
```

It works but it also flags whenever I have a `print()` statement specified in a documentation comment like this:

```
/// some comment mentioning print("hello") <- Error here
func myFunc() {}
```

How can I alter the regex so it ignores the `print` statement whenever it's in a documentation comment?

Comment: Why do you flag print statements in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to disable the rule for specific places in comments?

Comment: @Sulthan Because I don't want them inside my swift package. I've no idea if that's easier or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a custom rule can specify what type of code will match. The property is called `match_kinds`, example from Swiftlint Readme:

```
match_kinds: # SyntaxKinds to match. optional.
   - comment
   - identifier
```

Specifying `identifier` should be enough for your use case.

Comment: "scanner: while scanning for the next token in line ..."